# How to get messages as array instead of html block in magento

Tags: magento

at my template

> checkout/cart.phtml

There is one line

> echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();

Which returns html block of messages like errors

How can I get this messages as array instead of entire HTML Block ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In magento, there are 4 types of messages.

- Error
- Warning
- Notice
- Success

You can use following method to get all messages as a collection of array.

```
 $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages();
```

If you specify the type of message that you need to retrieve inside `getMessages()`, you will get only that type of messages as an array. ie

```
$this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages('error');
$this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages('warning');
$this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages('notice');
$this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages('success');
```

Comment: i got messages array $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages('error')

It contains some "object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Error" at each element

i see error message , type etc.

But how can I detect to which product Item Does each message belong ?

Comment: please show me the error message that you are getting

Comment: You need to set a message for each product through controller. Then you can get those messages using the above method.

Comment: <?php
$getErrorMessages = $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessages('error');
var_dump($getErrorMessages);

Comment: output 
=======
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Error)#199 (6) {
["_type":protected]=>
string(5) "error"
["_code":protected]=>
string(159) "Quantity of items for "My Product Name" is not possible"
["_class":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["_method":protected]=>
string(0) ""
["_identifier":protected]=>
NULL
["_isSticky":protected]=>
bool(false)
}
}

Comment: Ok you are setting this message through your controller right ? There you need to include the `product id` or an anything that give a hint to the procudt along with the message. This way you can trace the prodcuct. There is no other way in my knowledge.

Comment: no it is not my Controller. It is via core one. so I need to rewrite it via my controller at local. Right ?

Comment: you can set new messages through your controller. I don't get what you are trying to achieve ? Make a study on magento messages

Comment: I need to know what message from array belongs to Item product at current page ) at here /checkout/cart

Comment: at this page /checkout/cart I have the product's list being added to cart and some added quantity is exceeded. I have message with name product but There is no id product. I can parse product name from message and detect product item by name )

Comment: its a vast topic. you raise another question by specifying what exactly you need